# Calculation of TOA radiance from Sentinel-2 1C product reflectance

Tags: sentinel-2, reflectance, toa-calibration, sentinel-hub

I was trying to convert the Sentinel-2 1C product to radiance and came across two links [first](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285996/convert-sentinel-2-1c-product-from-reflectance-to-radiance) once says

```
radiance = ((pixelValueBandX * cos(incidenceAngle) * solarIrradianceBandX) / (pi * d2)) / 10000

where d2 is 1.0/U
```

Where as [second](https://github.com/umwilm/SEN2COR/blob/96a00464bef15404a224b2262accd0802a338ff9/sen2cor/L2A_Tables.py#L1937) one says

```
rad = rho * cos(radians(sza)) * Es * sc / (pi * d2)
where: d2 = 1.0 / U
scale: 1 / (0.001 * 1000) = 1 (default)
```

So, I have few questions amongst the two which one is correct. I don't see any scaling factor in the first one. Moreover, does the incidence angle here denotes the value of `Mean_Sun_Angle.ZENITH_ANGLE` from file `MTD_TL.xml`?

Also, Let's say i do atmospheric correction using SEN2COR or DOS. I would get the BOA reflectance, right? So, then how do i convert it to a BOA radiance?